# Sequence in Lisp

Tags: lisp, scheme, common-lisp

Hi
What is sequence in Lisp ? and what is difference between sequence and list in Lisp ?
thanks.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Sequence-Functions.html

Comment: Also, I hate being the "accept more answers" police, but you've asked plenty of questions and it's about time you accept some answers.  People have been pretty helpful to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sequence can be a list, string or vector.  Sequences are somewhat more general than lists.

Comment: In Common Lisp, at least, a string is-a vector, so this statement is true, if slightly redundant.

Comment: @Ken, specifically, a string is a vector with element-type character (and a base-string is one with element-type base-character, usually limited to ASCII).

Answer (score 3):

In Common Lisp, a list or a vector is a sequence.

However, lists and vectors have different performance characteristics because of their different underlying implementations (as linked-lists or arrays respectively).

In general, your best bet for basic questions about the language should probably be the Common Lisp Hyperspec, which is a highly hyperlinked version of the language standard. So, for instance, the [Hyperspec entry on SEQUENCE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_seq.htm) will tell you that both lists and vectors are sequences, but also suggests that other types might qualify as sequences as well, and provide links to its entries on lists, vectors, etc..

A good second stop is the lispdoc search tool, which searches the Hyperspec and the text of a few books on the language. So, for instance, [the lispdoc results for sequence](http://lispdoc.com/?q=sequence&search=Full%20text%20search) includes hits on the free online text for Practical Common Lisp, which also summarizes the language's [standard sequence functions](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/collections.html).

Comment: I find Common Lisp The Language easier to read (for such general questions) than HyperSpec.